# How to preserve "building blocks" of neural net?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I am making a kind of neural network, with neurons and "synapses". It kind of resembles turings type b nets, connections can go anywhere. It starts with a randomly generated net that has random connections between the neurons. There are both electrical and chemical variant with different effects on the neurons. To the point:

A net is basically a series of neurons with connections to other neurons. I cant figure out how to do "crossover" to form new generations of nets based on the best performing parents. More specifically, if I combine them based on single connections, I will break any potential "structure" or function that may have formed from a certain set of neurons and connections.

I considered splitting the network map, say, taking half from one parent and half from the other, but that may still break any potential functions that may have been created.

It is higly likely that I am missing something, I am learning this as I go.

Is there some way of doing this?

Comment: Is the number of neurons fixed? If it is then you can encode the synapses as a weight matrix of the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are evolving the network structure **and** weights, there is an excellent algorithm called [NEAT](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~kstanley/neat.html).

If you are evolving the weights only, you have several possibilites, but the most basic one is use the weight matrix of the network graph as a genotype. Then, crossover can be done using any continuous GA crossover method, like SBX or BLX-alpha.

The problem of breaking functionality (most often by mutation) is common and can be solved by e.g. fitness sharing (NEAT uses it) or some other mechanism which protects modified individuals for certain amount of time.

Comment: NEAT looks interesting. I will have to study it and see if I can understand it. I started out making things complicated, I made chemical synapses that can be inhibitory or excitatory on the neuron effected, so that it can be silenced or made to fire, and they work for a certain amount of time. I started adding lots of stuff, like the ability for neurons to sense eachother firing even though they were not connected but were close to eachother and that could cause new connections to form. The naive thought was that it would be able to adjust itself. I will have to simplify it. I will study neat!

Comment: @user2333489 I think you are trying something too complicated. Artificial neural networks are very simplified, they work in discrete time, etc. If you are doing some simulation of a real-world neurons, fine, but if you want to use the network as a regression model or as a controlling algorithm or something like that, I suggest you simplify things and use perceptron-based networks.